# Problemas con composer-laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, composer

Buen dia, tengo 2 proyectos, el principal asi por decirlo, y otro que le llamo de pruebas, que solo voy cargando paquetes o codigo antes de hacerlo en el principal, en fin, ambos son laravel 9, entonces el problema es el siguiente: en mi proyecto de pruebas cargue a traves de composer el paquete a continuación: https://packagist.org/packages/selective/xmldsig y en su documentacion indica que debe cargarse de la siguiente forma:

```
composer require selective/xmldsig
```

Todo bien, hice pruebas, modifique las clases etc, todo chevere, pero al momento de hacer lo mismo en mi proyecto principal, no me reconoce las clases del paquete.

Si efectuo un `$var= new XmlSigner();` me marca error al crear el objeto, pero en mi proyecto de pruebas no.

como puedo solucionar esto?

Edit: VScode me marca como error `"undefined type"` en mi proyecto principal, y soy nuevo con esto de laravel y composer.

Edit:
archivo composer.json de mi proyecto de desarrollo principal

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.0.2",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
        "laravel/framework": "^9.2",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^2.14.1",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.7",
        "robrichards/xmlseclibs": "^3.1",
        "selective/xmldsig": "^2.4"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^3.6",
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^6.1",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5.10",
        "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^1.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

Archivo composer.json de mi proyecto de pruebas y chucherias

```
    {
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.0",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0.5",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
        "laravel/framework": "^9.0",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^2.14",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.7",
        "livewire/livewire": "^2.10",
        "ricorocks-digital-agency/soap": "^1.6",
        "robrichards/xmlseclibs": "^3.1",
        "selective/xmldsig": "^2.4",
        "wire-elements/modal": "^1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/breeze": "^1.8",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^6.1",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5.10",
        "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^1.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

Comment: será que tus entornos no tiene las mismas extensiones php; y pareciera que a tu entorno de producción le faltara la extensión de xml ...

Comment: te comento que resolvi, borrando el paquete con composer, lo volvi a cargar y recien reconocio la clase que queria usar del paquete, pero ahora surge otro problema, en una de las clases del paquete instalado, no reconoce algunos metodos o clases, son entornos de desarrollo, misma version de laravel, la unica diferencia es que uno no tiene instalado livewire (mi proyecto principal de desarrollo), pero el otro si tiene livewire (de pruebas y chucherias).
Mas alla  de eso, no tienen diferencia, fueron creados con 2 horas de diferencia.

Comment: desactiva opcache ...

Comment: aun persiste el problema xd

Comment: en la clase que quiero utilizar, en varias secciones crea un objeto para excepciones $var= new XmlSignatureValidatorException(...)    y en este ahora me sale como undefinedtype,   y en unas 3 secciones utiliza el metodo queryDomNode(....)  y no me reconoce, esta ultima es un metodo del paquete xmlReader, que lo tengo incluido en la cabecera con USE (esto en mi proyecto principal de desarrollo), pero en el de pruebas no necesito ni usar el USE XMLREADER y todo bien

Comment: cuando tienes ese tipo de errores esta asociado a paquetes que requiere tu implementación que no están instaladas ... el error que me indicas asumo que esta ocurriendo internamente en tu librería ... puedes por favor subir los dos archivo de instalación de componer para compararlos??? como que me huele a que falta algo como requiere: {'ext-xml'}

Comment: como subo ficheros aqui? xd, soy nuevo en esta plataforma

Comment: copia el texto y lo pegas como en word: CTRL+C y depues haca CTRL+V

Comment: le das en editar a tu post y lo pones abajito ... y yo te ayudo a formatearlo ...

Comment: los dos ... el de desarrollo y el de producción ..

Comment: listo! ya estan ambos!

Comment: no se parecen en lo mas minimo nisiquiera el autoload psr-4 ...

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136194/discussion-between-arcanisgk507-and-gmiguel-s).

Comment: si, me equivoque copiando otro archivo, ya lo edite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cierra y Vuelve a abrir el VSCode ... por algún motivo estos editores open sources cachean los errores y no detectan cambios tan importante como lo son la instalación de librería y paquetería por composer.

Otro motivo puede ser que la instalación de tu entorno de desarrollo no tenga las extensiones que tiene tu entorno de producción. con estas dos revisiones no debes tener problemas.

Answer (score 0):

Solución:

1: Borrar el paquete y volver a cargarlo con el mismo composer.

2: El resto de problemas de que no reconocia algunas clases o metodos, Abrir y cerrar el VSCode xD, vaya vaya xD

Muchas Gracias ArcanisGK507, no se como etiquetarte xD